# Seg Fault With Malloc() in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have written a program and I have created this structure

```
struct position_found
{
 int row;
 int column;
struct position_found *next;
};
typedef struct position_found position_found, *position_found_ptr;
```

and then i use this function to create a new node type position_found

```
position_found_ptr new_position_found_node(int row, int column)
{
 position_found_ptr x;

 x=(position_found_ptr)malloc(sizeof(position_found));
 if(x==NULL)
 {
    printf("out of memory");
    exit(2);
 }
 x->row=row;
 x->column=column;
 x->next=NULL;
 return x;
}
```

The problem is that x=(position_found_ptr)malloc(sizeof(position_found)); presents seg fault, but if i print something right before this, for example printf("k");, malloc will work properly and my program will continiue. I've tried using the function on her own in a test programm and it works perfectly. Do you have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Yes, you have invoked undefined behaviour *elsewhere* in your program.

Comment: have you included stdlib.h ?

Comment: Run your code through `valgrind` or another memory debugger. It should help you track down where your real problem is.

Comment: sounds like your issue has its origin in the code you are not showing

Comment: @Claptrap yes i have included stdlib.h

Comment: @FatalError thank you i will try valgrind, hopefully i will find the problem

Comment: your code that you show looks like valid c-code (part from the cast of malloc). your problem probably is somewhere else corrupting the heap/stack

Comment: Your code compiles and runs correctly in GCC. What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you want , put your whole code so i can debug it with gdb (or you can do it yourself ) :D

but the answer for your second question : 
 the reason is that when you run a program , in has some memory size (except your variables and other     things ) its about OS ! 
if you have a problem with working with memory (like your code) you get segmentation fault ! 
but when you add some line(s) of code  ,this changes the data order writing in memory cells so that your remaining code doesn't write on illegal memory cells ! :D

for example : 
if before adding printf("k"); you were on x1234 which is illegal and because of that you've got seg fault , after adding that , you went on x4323 so this is legal and everything is ok :D

you can use "gdb" to "disassemble" to check what i said  :D !!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :D  I asked because it looked pretty strange what was happening and i had no idea why. I will try debugging with gdb and if that doesn't work i will post my whole code, hoping for your help :D